# it's possible to animate only one angle to rotation

Tags: animation, aframe

Using Aframe 0.6.1 I'm trying to make a button in the scene who begin an animation. This animation must rotate only the X angle of camera to 0. I like to leave all other angles same as before (ok, Z angle never moved, so like to only save Y angle).

an approach

```
<a-camera>
    <a-animation begin="cameraToHorizonEvent" attribute="rotation.x" to="0" dur="2000"></a-animation>
</a-camera>
```

Here "rotation.x" DON'T WORK, something like this it's what I like. It's possible?

---

A temporal solution is to use animation-component, set rotation as property (attribute in a-animation), and do cameraEntity.setAttribute('animation', 'to', '0'+camRotY+camRotZ) and other stuff but I think that another solution can be

Thanks